# Remove first two words from string

Tags: r

I have a text:

```
s="Daniel S Hi What are you doing today"
s1="Mary G I am occupied with some work today"
s2="Cindy U Hey you guys are joining today's conference"
```

I want to remove first two words from all of the text, I have just given 3 text but there are more thousand text like this, first two words pattern going to be same, first word is some name and second word is a single alphabet.

Expected output:

```
s="Hi What are you doing today"
s1="I am occupied with some work today"
s2="Hey you guys are joining today's conference"
```

Comment: While the regex approach isn't wrong, a more tangible approach would be to split your string by the spaces, and remove the first two indices of the result. E.g. `strsplit(X, " ")[-c(1,2),]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove first two words from each text using regex.

```
x <- c("Daniel S Hi What are you doing today", "Mary G I am occupied with some work today", "Cindy U Hey you guys are joining today's conference")
sub('^\\w+\\s\\w+\\s', '', x)

#[1] "Hi What are you doing today"                 "I am occupied with some work today"         
#[3] "Hey you guys are joining today's conference"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
str
[1] "Daniel S Hi What are you doing today"               
[2] "Mary G I am occupied with some work today"          
[3] "Cindy U Hey you guys are joining today's conference"
sapply(sapply(strsplit(str, split = ' '), function(x) x[3:length(x)]), paste, collapse = ' ')
[1] "Hi What are you doing today"                 "I am occupied with some work today"         
[3] "Hey you guys are joining today's conference"
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
list2env(Map(function(x){gsub("\\w+\\s*\\w+\\s*(.*)", "\\1", x)}, 
    mget(ls(pattern = "^s.*"))), .GlobalEnv)
```